# Having Trouble Returning a Count of Images Per Gallery Using MSSQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm currently trying to add another column (PictureCount) into my result set that returns a count of images located within each unique gallery from another table. (GalleryID links them together.) Every GalleryID could have anywhere from 3 to 20 MediaID's associated with them.

I'm not an expert at SQL so I could use some help. I'm not even sure if its possible to return the count I'm looking for.

Thanks!

[image: Here's a simple view of the 2 tables.]

A SQL Fiddle to help you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72935/16

Here's my current query that returns everything I need except a Count column which I cant figure out how to do.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate 
    ORDER BY b.MediaThumb DESC) AS Rn
    FROM Media b
    INNER JOIN Galleries A
    ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
    WHERE b.IsPlug = 0 AND b.IsHidden = 0
),

CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
    1 Rn
    FROM Media b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Galleries A
    ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
)

SELECT *, NewID = NEWID() FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1 and MediaTypeID = 4

UNION ALL

SELECT *, NewID = NEWID() FROM CTE2 WHERE rn = 1 and MediaTypeID = 4 and GalleryID is NULL
ORDER BY GalleryDate DESC, GalleryID DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH cte As
(
   SELECT
      a.GalleryID As GalleryID_A,
      a.GalleryTitle,
      a.GalleryDate,
      b.*,

      -- You only need to partition by GalleryID:
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.GalleryID ORDER BY b.MediaThumb DESC) As Rn,

      -- This will return the number of media records per gallery:
      COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY b.GalleryID) As Rc
   FROM
      Media As b
      -- The LEFT JOIN will include media with no gallery,
      -- so your second CTE is not needed:
      LEFT JOIN Gallery As A
      ON b.GalleryID = A.GalleryID
   WHERE
      -- This filter needs to be within the CTE,
      -- otherwise you'll exclude galleries where the last
      -- media is not type 4:
      b.MediaTypeID = 4
)
SELECT
   *
FROM
   cte
WHERE
   rn = 1
ORDER BY 
   GalleryDate DESC, 
   GalleryID DESC
;
```

Comment: WOW, Thank you Richard for the quick response and the perfect answer. Kind Regards!